# New-MailboxExportRequest and 24 hours later?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2019

Whenever I use New-MailboxExportRequest to export a mailbox to a pst file on a network share it exports perfectly fine though 24 hours after the export finishes the file seems to be updated again and gets its modified date updated. Everything is working I just noticed it when the pst files would be picked up a on two nightly backups as being changed. Does anyone know what Exchange is doing / why this is happening?

The files are perfectly fine I'm just really curious about what the 24 hour later update is doing. It only seems to happen once 24 hours after the export and never again.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Does the account under which you ran the export command have read access to Microsoft Exchange System Objects OU (in AD) in which the SystemMailbox resides?

Though, to bypass any duplication or other issues, you should exclude those items from the initial exports and only do them one at a time. Also, The old PST files from the first export have been moved to a new folder so that you can create a new PST file with the latest new export command. You can also refer [this link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fbad9734-7e3c-48a3-8767-e00dc26a81b3/what-happend-newmailboxexportrequest-cmdlet-in-exchange-2013-sp1-is-missing?forum=exchangesvradmin).

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Before I do the export I remove the previous pst file so it is for sure a new file being created. I'm doing the export with the domain admin account and it does have full access. As I mentioned the export works fine and I can use the pst files it's just exactly 24 hours later exchange does something to the file which updates their modified date. After that exchange doesn't touch the files again.